Is every selection from compact-valued upper semi continuous multivalued maps Borel measurable?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, and let $F: X \to 2^Y$ be a set-valued map such that $F(x)$ is compact for all $x \in X$ and $F$ is upper semi-continuous. Assume that $X$ is compact. Then, $F(X)$ is compact in $Y$, as a well known consequences of these assumptions.
We aim to show that any selector $f: X \to Y$, where $f(x) \in F(x)$ for all $x \in X$, is Borel measurable.
Since $F(X)$ is compact, we can cover it by finitely many open balls $B_\epsilon(y_i)$, where $y_i \in F(x_i)$ for some $x_i \in X$. That is,
$$
F(X) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_\epsilon(y_i).
$$
For each $i$, the preimage $F^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y_i))$ is a Borel set in $X$ due to the upper semi-continuity of $F$.
We can find disjoint Borel sets $(X_i)_i$ such that  $X_i \subset F^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y_i))$, which are Borel sets and
$$
\bigcup_i X_i = F^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y_i)).
$$
Each $F(X_i) \subset B_\epsilon(y_i)$.
Now, we define the function $\tilde{f}_\epsilon: X \to Y$ by
$$
\tilde{f}_\epsilon(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N 1_{X_i}(x) y_i.
$$
This function is Borel measurable because each indicator function $1_{X_i}(x)$ is Borel measurable, and the finite sum of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable.
For each $x \in X$, we have $f(x) \in F(x) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_\epsilon(y_i)$, so there exists an $i$ such that $f(x) \in B_\epsilon(y_i)$. Thus, for all $x \in X$, the difference $d(f(x), \tilde{f}_\epsilon(x))$ is at most $\epsilon$.
Since $f(x)$ is the pointwise limit of the Borel measurable functions $\tilde{f}_\epsilon(x)$, where each $\tilde{f}_\epsilon$ is Borel measurable, it follows that $f$ is Borel measurable.
My problem with the argument above is that, this construction is not specific to $f$. I'm not sure where the proof went wrong. Any help is appreciated.
